# Delay between for loop iteration (python)

Tags: python, loops, web

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946232/how-to-add-some-delay-between-each-iteration-of-for-loop-in-c) possible in Python? I wrote a great loop/script in Python and I’d like to add this delay to it if at all possible.

```
map(firefox.open, ['http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + str(i) for i in range(x))], [2] * x)
```

Where shall I put the `sleep(6)` in this?

Answer (score 25):

You can do that using `time.sleep(some_seconds)`.

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print i
    sleep(0.5)    #in seconds
```

#### Implementation

Here is a cool little implementation of that: (Paste it in a .py file and run it)

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(101):
    print '\r'+str(i)+'% completed',
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

map(firefox.open, ['http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + str(i) for i in range(x))], [2] * x)

Comment: `map(firefox.open, ['http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + str(i) for i in range(x))], [2] * x)`

Where shall I put the `sleep(6)` in this?

Comment: @user3072758, You will have to un-comprehend your list-comprehension and write it out in traditional style

Comment: @user3072758, I know how disappointing it can be when you write a great list-comprehension and then you have to split it open like some kind of savage. :)

Comment: I literally have no idea what to do now. I guess I could go back to just running this multiple times. I wanted to put the delay in so that Firefox is capable of registering all of the queries instead of “almost” all of the queries.

Comment: @user3072758, Can you blow out your code and write tradition for-loops. If yes, then I can help you. I don't really know about `firefox.open` and stuff so I am currently not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want it to start on one and emulate a stopwatch:

```
import time
def count_to(number):
    for i in range(number):
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
        if i >= number:
            print('Time is up')
            break
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in python you should use 'time' module:

```
     >>> import time
     >>> list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
     >>> for i in list1:
         time.sleep(1)#sleep for 1 second 
         print i
```

output :

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
```